# Merging rooms in Archimesh

Tags: archimesh-add-on

I'm pretty new in Blender, using it (version 3.0) with Archimesh (version 1.2.2) to model a house.

Archimesh is very helpful when building single rooms. But if more than one room is needed I  can't find out how to merge rooms together without manually align them in a pixel hell and overlapping walls.

[image: Duplicated Wall and Merging Hell]

Not to mention that, if I need to create door/passways, I would need to create them in every wall that overlaps. In image below I would like to create a door that connects the smaller room with the larger room, but seems I need to create in both walls at exact same location.

[image: How to make a door without extra work]

Probably I´m doing in wrong way. Because of that I came here to ask for advice, since the Archimesh documentation is poor and the official tutorial videos do not explain how to handle multiple rooms, just single ones.

Comment: This short video may help ( at 5'34) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZD8sSX7NtU And this one shows other interesting things but he goes so quick i cant follow : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0k9kZwUhpo